# How to extract a tarball?

Tags: zip, elixir, compression, tar

### Background

I have a release file inside a `tarball`.  However I want the final release to have some additional files and to move things around, for the convenience of the user.

This means I need to do 3 things:

1. Extract the contents of the tarball into a folder
2. Add the extra files to said folder and move some items around
3. compress everything again and call it a day

### Problem

While I have it clear on how to execute step 2, using `File` and friends, I have tried several ways to do steps 1 and 3 and I failed.

I have tried using `:zip`, but it returns a bad encoding error, probably because the file is not a `zip` but `tar` instead.

I am also aware of  `File.open("path", :read, :compressed)`, but I don't want to read anything, I want to extract it into a new folder.

I also checked [`Unzip`](https://github.com/akash-akya/unzip) but it does not fit my use case.

### Question

How can I extract a `tar` file into a folder and compress a folder into a `tar` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to extract the file using:

```
:ok = :erl_tar.extract("tar_path", [{:cwd, "tmp"}, :compressed])
```

This will extract the tar file into the tmp folder. Once there I can do the rest !